# MySQL query optimization using where statement

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on big data base that contains >1 Million records, i am using the below query to full out records based on my criteria but it is too slow even though i index the primary key.

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title, productID, catID, description, productUrl, 
    regularPrice, salePrice, imageUrl, merID, created_at, 
    updated_at, name, link, source 
FROM products p, advertisers a 
WHERE (title LIKE '%headphone%' OR description LIKE '%headphone%') 
AND catID=22 
AND regularPrice IS NOT NULL 
AND p.merID = a.advertID
```

Can anyone help me on how to optimize the query?

Thanks,

EDIT:

Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `productID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `catID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `productUrl` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `regularPrice` double(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salePrice` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `imageUrl` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `merID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `advertisers` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `advertID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `logo` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT DISTINCT title, productID, catID, description, productUrl, regularPrice, salePrice, imageUrl, merID, created_at, updated_at, name, link, source FROM products p, advertisers a WHERE (title LIKE '%headphone%' OR description LIKE '%headphone%') AND catID=22 AND regularPrice IS NOT NULL AND p.merID = a.advertID;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------+----------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys       | key      | key_len | ref               | rows   | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------+----------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | ALL    | merID               | NULL     | NULL    | NULL              | 682242 |     1.89 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | eq_ref | advertID,advertID_2 | advertID | 152     | datafeeds.p.merID |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------+----------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------+------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Show `CREATE TABLE` query

Comment: Use the `EXPLAIN` feature mysql offers. See the documentation for that. It allows you to understand exactly _how_ mysql is able to select the matches, what indexes it uses and what might be missing.

Comment: I'd recommend not using JOIN syntax that is about two decades out of date. Otherwise, make sure the joined fields (on both sides) are also indexed.

Comment: @aliocee, does exists any indexes? Would be great to show `CREATE TABLE` for `advertisers` table too.

Comment: Please show result of EXPLAIN as @arkascha says above

Answer (score 0):

check for index in the join key  merID for products and advertID for advertisers

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
    title
  , productID
  , catID
  , description
  , productUrl
  , regularPrice
  , salePrice
  , imageUrl
  , merID
  , created_at
  , updated_at
  , name
  , link
  , source 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN  advertisers a  ON p.merID = a.advertID
WHERE (title LIKE '%headphone%' OR description LIKE '%headphone%') 
AND catID=22 
AND regularPrice IS NOT NULL
```

coulb be useful a composite index on the (probably ) more selective columns column

```
 (catID, merID)
```

regularPrice, title  and description  due the use of like and si not null don't should be useful in composite index

Comment: `Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.` i am getting this warning

Comment: The warning  .. is showed when ?? what you are trying to do?  and what mean  ` Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available` ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL support full text indexes for InnoDB tables since version 5.6.

I recomend you to use full text search.

```
ALTER TABLE products  
ADD FULLTEXT (title, description);
```

And replace

```
WHERE (title LIKE '%headphone%' OR description LIKE '%headphone%')
```

To

```
WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('headphone');
```

Comment: Great news! Still I strongly suggest that you learn about the suggested `EXPLAIN` feature to be able to find a solution to index issues yourself.

Comment: @aliocee, You can use wildcard only from right side: `AGAINST ('headphone*')`. But you have other advantages. Read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html